# Python recursive object refrence in Tree datastructure

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, tree, object-reference

I am somehow new to python. I needed to use tree to store some data (file paths), The problem is when I generate the tree it seems that all objects after the root reference the same object, although step by step debugging showed the opposite. Here is my (minimized) code:
first the node class:

```
class PathElement:  

  Element = ""
  IsStatic = True
  Children = []
  ChildrenCount = 0 

  def __init__(self, Element, IsStatic=True):
      self.Element = Element
      self.IsStatic = IsStatic
      if not IsStatic:
          self.Element = [] 

  def AddChild(self, Child):
      print(self, "    ", Child)
      self.Children.append(Child)
      self.ChildrenCount = len(self.Children)
      return Child
```

The Children is list of PathElement nodes. The code that build the tree:

```
def UnFoldAndCheck(self):
    Path = PathElement("root")
    Handler = Path
    Index = 0
    Count = len(self.Path)
    while Index < Count:

        element = self.Path[Index]

        if something:
            Child = None
            Child = PathElement(element)
            Handler.AddChild(Child)
            Handler = None #Those added to debug the problem
            Handler = Child
        elif other_thing:
            if condition:
                if some_large_condition:
                    ChildExec = None
                    ChildExec = PathElement(element, False)
                    for i in range(0, 5):
                        ChildExec.Element.append(self.Path[Index + i])
                    Handler.AddChild(ChildExec)
                    Handler = None
                    Handler = ChildExec
                    Index += 4
            elif another_condition:
                ChildOp = None
                ChildOp = PathElement(element, False)
                Handler.AddChild(ChildOp)
                Handler = None
                Handler = ChildOp
            elif some_else_condition:
                 if condition:
                    ChildExec = None
                    ChildExec = PathElement(element, False)
                    for i in range(0, 3):
                        ChildExec.Element.append(self.Path[Index + i])
                    Handler.AddChild(ChildExec)
                    Handler = None
                    Handler = ChildExec
                    Index += 2

                elif different_condition:
                    ChildExec = None
                    ChildExec = PathElement(element, False)
                    for i in range(0, 3):
                        ChildExec.Element.append(self.Path[Index + i])
                    Handler.AddChild(ChildExec)
                    Handler = None
                    Handler = ChildExec
                    Index += 1
        Index += 1
    return Path
```

My problem is that after the tree is built when I use it it will have always same structure:
root -> object with 3 exact nodes -> same object -> same object to infinity
while the expected is:
root -> object -> first children -> second children -> third children -> etc
I'm sure the problem is related to how python handle object references but I can't see where the problem exactly. Any help?

### Update:

I reproduced the problem with smaller code (same class PathElement):

```
from PathElement import PathElement
Path = PathElement("root")
Handler = Path
for i in range(1,6):
   Child = PathElement("child"+str(i))
   Handler.AddChild(Child)
   Handler = Child
Tree = Path
while True:
   print(Tree.Element)
   if len(Tree.Children) > 0:
      Tree = Tree.Children[0]
   else:
       break
```

This code will make infinite loop

Comment: First of all, why not use a `for` loop instead of the `while Index < Count` loop? Also take a look at the [python naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for changing your variable names.

Comment: I used for loop, but then I realized that I need while since (as you can see) I need to make forward jumps by increment the Index by more than 1.

Comment: I made some additions to run your code, and it does not give the result you say. Can you give the real code or a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? In addition to Jakob comment: do not store the `children_count` but use `len(children)` and use a loop `while path: ... path.pop(0)` (on a copy of path if you don't want to consume it). You can then remove the index.

Comment: @jferard I added minimized code that reproduce the problem. And thank you, path.pop(0) look cleaner I'll will consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you come from Java or a similar language. It's important to stick with Python's conventions (Jakob Sachs gave you va link to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) because that makes your mistakes are easier to identify.

Now, what's wrong here? When you wrote:

```
class PathElement():  
  Children = []
  Element = ""
  IsStatic = True
  ChildrenCount = 0
```

You don't give the initial value of instance fields. *You create an initialize class (static) fields.* Hence, `Children` is a static field of the class `PathElement`. Here's a illustration of that:

```
class A():
    i = []

a = A()
b = A()

a.i.append(1) 
b.i.append(2) 
assert a.i == b.i == [1,2]
```

What happens when you try to make read the leftmost part of the tree (child 0, child 0 of child 0, ...)?

```
while True:
   print(Tree.Element)
   if len(Tree.Children) > 0:
      Tree = Tree.Children[0]
   else:
       break
```

Just replace `Tree.Children` by what it is really: `PathElement.Children`, that is the static field `Children` of the class `PathElement`:

```
while True:
   print(Tree.Element)
   if len(PathElement.Children) > 0:
      Tree = PathElement.Children[0] # Tree has always the same value.
   else:
       break
```

Now, a example of what you can write:

```
class PathElement:  
    def __init__(self, element):
        self.__element = element
        self.__children = []

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.__children.append(child)

    def children(self):
        return list(self.__children)

    def element(self):
        return self.__element

path = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

root = PathElement("root")
handler = root
while path:
    child = PathElement(path.pop(0)) # you can put some conditions here, take more elements of path, ...
    handler.add_child(child)
    handler = child

def dfs(node):
    for c in node.children():
        yield c.element()
        yield from dfs(c)

print (list(dfs(root)))
# a b c d e f
```

Comment: Wow! great answer, actually I managed to solve the problem using "dirty" hack by adding to addChild method this line before appending : _self.Children = list(self.Children)_ . However now I understand what was going on, and yes when I was writing the code I thought "Why doesn't this work like C trees" :) Thank you so much for the informative answer.